# What is the best way to make a shallow copy of a Python dictionary?

Tags: python

Assume we have a simple Python dictionary:

```
dict_ = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
```

Which is the better way to copy this dictionary?

```
copy1 = dict(dict_)
copy2 = dict_.copy()
```

Is there a compelling reason to favour one approach over the other?

Comment: +1: very relevant question, as the answers show that the situation is not at all clear cut!

Comment: So much for "one obvious way to do it"...

Comment: On the other hand, define what you mean by "better".

Comment: The definition I had in mind is "more appropriate, advantageous, or well advised".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could favor option #1 (`dict(dict_)`) because of the principle of least surprise: you can do the same for lists: `list(list_)`, and lists don't have a `copy()` method.

That said, many good points were raised in the answers.  This indicates that **there might not be any obviously better solution**, and that both are fine, as long as you do what you intend to do (the point about subclassing `dict` might be crucial, in some codes, for instance).  So, I would just choose whatever feels right for your application given the points raised in the responses!

Comment: There are many great answers here, but for the benefit of future readers I'll select this one as it best conveys the lack of consensus.

Answer (score 8):

I always use the `dict` constructor: it makes it obvious that you are creating a new `dict` whereas calling the `copy` method on an object could be copying anything. Similarly for `list` I prefer calling the constructor over copying by slicing.

Note that if you use subclasses of `dict` using the `copy` method can get confusing:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> d['a']
0
>>> d.copy()
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 0})
>>> dict(d)
{'a': 0}
>>>
```

The `copy` method of `defaultdict` gives you another `defaultdict`, but unless you override `copy` in a subclass the default action is just to give you a `dict`:

```
>>> class MyDict(dict): pass

>>> d = MyDict(a=1)
>>> d
{'a': 1}
>>> type(d)
<class '__main__.MyDict'>
>>> type(d.copy())
<class 'dict'>
```

That means you have to know about the internal details of a subclass to know what type the `copy` method will return.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends... on what you actually intend to use it for. In  library, you may need to mutate a copy of some dict-like object, and you want a copy that is the same object. Other APIs must have an actual `dict`, so would create a new `dict` with the constructor method and use that one. But you lose the actual original type information (and methods) when you do that.  But overall, I would prefer the copy() method as it is clear it is a copy of of a dict-like object (not just a dict). That makes it more flexible (duck typing).

Answer (score 2):

The best would be `dict_.copy()` since the intention is self-descriptive. However, using the `dict` form you can create a copy with extra keys:

```
d = dict(a, zoo=1, zar=2)
```

which is equivalent, but shorter than:

```
d = a.copy()
d.update(zoo=1, zar=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Second one is better because it `explicitly` shows you are `copy`'ing.

Comment: The first option also explicitly shows that you are creating a new dictionary… (no downvote from me, though :)

Comment: Well the op intends to `copy` not create a new dictionary ;)

Comment: ...and as @Keith points out, works with duck typing, and as @Duncan points out, *can* be made to work when subclassing so you  get another instance of the derived type.

Comment: @Ismail: … however a new dictionary with the contents of the old dictionary is a copy. :)  There are good arguments on both sides.  It all depends on what one wants to achieve, especially in terms of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t like the `dict.copy()` method:

- it’s not clear from the name what kind of copy `.copy()` does
- subclasses have to overwrite it, or it’s semantic is completely hosed
- shallow copies can be done by other ways (the general `copy.copy()` or `dict()`)

Imagine a random class, e.g. `Uber`. – How would you try to make a copy of `u = Uber(...)`?

1. `dict(u)`
2. `Uber(u)`
3. `u.copy()`
4. `copy.copy(u)`

I would say that number 2. has the highest chances to work —or— to blow up. – Exactly what I want.